# how to import and use Fontello in vue/nuxt project

Tags: vue.js, svg, nuxt.js, fontello

so i have my svg image which i want to convert it to icon using Fontello to convert and import it to my nuxt project. but the configuration doesn't seem to work

this is what in my **nuxt.config.js** file

```
head: {
  css: [
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '~/assets/css/animation.css',
    '~/assets/css/fontello.css',
    '~/assets/css/fontello-ie7.css',
    '~/assets/css/fontello-ie7-codes.css', /*if IE 7 */
  ],
}
```

in my html page, i'm using

```
<i @click="goToChat" class="the-icons demo-icon icon-chat menu ic-menu">&#xe800;</i>
```

and my css file,

```
.demo-icon {
  font-family: "fontello";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  speak: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  width: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.2em;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

the problem is the css file counldn't read `font-family: "fontello";` did i config it wrong?

Comment: just a guess, but could it be because you specified the `css` property in the `head` configuration object and not the global `css` property?

Answer (score 0):

Stumble on the same issue just tonight and searched how to do it, **I tried your config and it works..**
Have you also imported the font folder provided by fontello which contains the actual font?

If you open the fontello.css file you will see the @font-face property with url reference to thos font files make sure the url is the right one (easiest solution is to import font and css folder from fontello.zip) so that your assets foolder looks something like that
Assets
 - css
 - font
 - images